# TinyMCE can not read video tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tinymce

In react js I am using tinymce editor. When I am trying to upload video via tinymce on server I put url inside video tag but it show img tag

There is any fixes for it?

P.S. If I put video in iframe it works but from iframe I can not control autoplay

Comment: Hi Zura, can you please provide some details on your configuration and example content from the editor? When you say "I put url inside video tag", can you please elaborate on how you're doing this?

Comment: Hi Delass, this is example: . When uploaded video url returns from server I use editor.insertContent(<video controls><source src="VIDEO_URL"></video>) but tinymce convert it into img tag

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot replicate the same behaviour you're describing. Are you able to replicate it on https://fiddle.tiny.cloud? Alternatively, you may want to review my example at https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/Hqhaab. After opening the page, click "Get Content" at the bottom and the site will show you a preview of the HTML content and the raw HTML output.

Comment: In Your example I can not play video, I want to be able to watch video in tynimce editor, this is what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

The image placeholder is by design. One of the many reasons is to reduce the overheads within the editor whilst a user is editing the content.

If you wish to extend the functionality of videos within the TinyMCE editor, Tiny offers an [Enhanced Media Embed Plugin](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/mediaembed/).

*Note: The Enhanced Media Embed Plugin is only available for paid TinyMCE subscriptions.*